Youtube API set sound used in short
I am trying to upload a few shorts using Youtube's Upload API and I want to set the sound used in the video. Where it displays song used in short Here it shows the song used in the video and allows the user to see other videos using this song. I want to make my videos discoverable under the artists song.
Youtube API seems to not have an option for this I don't know where else to start.

Can you edit such song after upload when you proceed without the API?

Are you sure you want to do that?  It will make it very easy to sue you for copyright violation.

@TimRoberts 100% it's all my content

@BenjaminLoison yes I believe so
